# Docker not found in circleci config

Tags: circleci-2.0, circleci

Why is `docker` not found? Do I need to use a different docker image than `debian:latest`? I want the latest debian image so does that mean I need to manually install Docker?

```
orbs:
  aws-ecr: circleci/aws-ecr@6.2.0
version: 2.1

workflows:
  # Build every commit on every branch without pushing to ECR
  build_image:
    jobs:
      - build_image

jobs:
  build_image:
    docker:
      - image: debian:latest
    steps:
      - aws-ecr/build-image:
          account-url: AWS_ACCOUNT_URL
          repo: node
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try adding,`- steup_remote_docker` before `- aws-ecr/build-image:`